# Series convergence - factorial over products

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Does
$$
\sum_{n\ =\ 1}{n!\over
\left(\,\sqrt{\,2\,}\, + 1\,\right)
\left(\,\sqrt{\,2\,}\, + 2\,\right)\ldots
\left(\,\sqrt{\,2\,}\, + n - 1\,\right)\left(\,\sqrt{\,2\,}\, + n\,\right)}\quad
$$
converge or diverge ?

I used the D'Alambert criterion, but it gives $D = 1$, and I have no idea what other criterion I could use.

Comment: This sum in fact has a closed form - it's just $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-1}=1+\sqrt{2}$. I have written up a solution showing this [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100474/a-complicated-infinite-sum-with-a-nice-solution-sum-n-1-infty-prod-k-1n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint 
since
$$a_{n}=\dfrac{n!}{(\sqrt{2}+1)(\sqrt{2}+2)\cdots(\sqrt{2}+n)}$$
$$\Longrightarrow \dfrac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}=\dfrac{n!}{(n+1)!}\cdot\dfrac{(\sqrt{2}+1)(\sqrt{2}+2)\cdots (\sqrt{2}+n+1)}{(\sqrt{2}+1)(\sqrt{2}+2)\cdots(\sqrt{2}+n)}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}+n+1}{n+1}$$
you can consider [Ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\dfrac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}-1\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{2}+n+1}{n+1}-1\right)=\sqrt{2}>1$$
so it is converges

Comment: Nice solution! Just brief note - we are not using the normal ratio test, but rather an extension which is called [Raabe's test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RaabesTest.html).