# Infinite sum of reciprocal of binomial $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n+k\choose n}$

Tags: combinatorics

Can anyone help me with this sum? Thanks!
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n+k\choose n} = \frac{1}{k-1}$$

---

My try:
Consider beta function $$\frac{B(k+1, n+1)} {(n+k+1)} = \frac1{n+k\choose n} $$ we try to integrate
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1(1-t)^{k+1}\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+k+1}\mathrm d t\\
=&\int _0^1(1-t)^{k+1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{t^{n+1}}{n+k+1}\mathrm d t\\
=&\int _0^1(1-t)^{k+1}t^{-k}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{t^{n+k+1}}{n+k+1}\mathrm d t\\
=&\int _0^1\int_0^t(1-t)^{k+1}t^{-k}\frac{s^{1+k}}{1-s}\mathrm d s\mathrm d t
\end{align*}

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1100474/

Answer (score 2):

A fix to your attempt: consider $$\frac1{\binom{n+k}n}=k\,\mathrm{B}(k,n+1)=k\int_0^1(1-t)^{k-1}t^n\,dt.$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, observe that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over{n+k\choose n}}
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\dots n\over(k+1)\dots(k+n)}
={}_2F_1(1,1;k+1;1)-1,$$
where ${}_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$ denotes the [Gaussian hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function), and apply [Gauss's summation theorem](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4#E20):
$$_2F_1(a,b;c;1)={\Gamma(c)\Gamma(c-a-b)\over\Gamma(c-a)\Gamma(c-b)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}, k\geq 2$; then
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{k-1}\left(\frac{n!}{(n+k-1)!}-\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+k)!}\right)=\frac{1}{k-1}\left(\frac{n!}{(n+k-1)!}-\frac{n!(n+1)}{(n+k-1)!(n+k)}\right)\\ &=\frac{n!}{(k-1)(n+k-1)!}\left(1-\frac{n+1}{n+k}\right)=\frac{n!}{(k-1)(n+k-1)!}\cdot\frac{k-1}{n+k}=\frac{n!}{(n+k-1)!(n+k)}=\frac{n!}{(n+k)!}
\end{align*}
so for $N\in\mathbb{N}$ we have
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N}\frac{n!}{(n+k)!}&=\frac{1}{k-1}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N}\left(\frac{n!}{(n+k-1)!}-\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+k)!}\right)=\frac{1}{k-1}\left(\frac{0!}{(k-1)!}-\frac{(N+1)!}{(N+k)!}\right)\\&=\frac{1}{k-1}\left(\frac{1}{(k-1)!}-\frac{1}{(N+k)(N+k-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(N+2)}\right)
\end{align*}
and it follows that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{(n+k)!}=\lim\limits_{N\to+\infty}\left[\frac{1}{k-1}\left(\frac{1}{(k-1)!}-\frac{1}{(N+k)(N+k-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(N+2)}\right)\right]=\frac{1}{(k-1)(k-1)!}$ thus $$k!\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{(n+k)!}=\frac{k!}{(k-1)(k-1)!}$$ and now it suffices to note that $$k!\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{(n+k)!}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{k!n!}{(n+k)!}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\frac{(n+k)!}{k!n!}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\binom{n+k}{k}}$$ and $$\frac{k!}{(k-1)(k-1)!}=\frac{k}{k-1}=\frac{(k-1)+1}{k-1}=1+\frac{1}{k-1}$$ to conclude that $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\binom{n+k}{k}}=1+\frac{1}{k-1}\text{, and finally }\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\binom{n+k}{k}}=\frac{1}{k-1}.\ \square$$